# List directories with dot directories last, then dot files

Tags: zsh, ls

I'm aware of the `ls` option `--group-directories-first` but that's not exactly what I want to achieve.

The output should be: (sorted by name ASC)

- Directories
- Hidden Directories
- Hidden Files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `ls` (the `-U` option to tell `ls` not to sort the file list is a GNU extension):

```
ls -lUd -- *(/) .*(/) .*(^/)
```

The problem though is that if any of those globs don't match, the command will be cancelled, so you could do:

```
myls() (
  setopt cshnullglob
  ls -lUd -- *(/) .*(/) .*(^/)
)
```

That emulates the `csh` behaviour whereby globs with no match expand to nothing as long as there's at least one glob that expands to something in the command.

Note that `zsh` globs never expand `.` and `..`, so those two will never be included.

Comment: Don't think I've ever seen `cshnullglob` before - nice.

Comment: adding localoptions with it will scope the cshnullglob to the function.

Comment: @llua, yes, but since we're executing a command anyway, we might as well limit the scope with a subshell (note the `(` instead of `{`)