# How can I list hidden directories, then directories, then hidden files and finally files with ls?

Tags: bash, ls, sort

I'm trying to figure out how to list the contents of a directory in the following group order:

1. Hidden directories
2. Non-hidden directories
3. All other hidden files (including regular files, symlinks, sockets)
4. All other non-hidden files (including regular files, symlinks, sockets)

Each group should be sorted A-Z, preferably case-insensitive.

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138829/22172) I tried the following:

```
ls -dlU .*/ */
```

This gets me half-way there by listing hidden directories and then non-hidden directories. The problem is it doesn't list any files.

I've also tried various ways of piping the output to `sort` with no luck.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could try with `LC_COLLATE=C ls -lA --group-directories-first` or `LANG=POSIX ls -lA --group-directories-first`. Though it works on my system (`en-US.UTF-8`), it sorts case-sensitive and would probably have some strange effects on systems with different locales/foreign characters.

Comment: @don_crissti nice. Any way to get it to ignore case?

Comment: I guess you could create your own locale definition (based on `C` but case insensitive or based on `en_US` but dot-sensitive). Yeah, I know this is half a year later but I stumbled upon this question while looking for some similar stuff...

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*'
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -name '.*'
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*'
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \! -name '.*'
```

Comment: +1. I would like to note that this omits anything that is neither a regular file nor a directory (e.g. symlink, socket), but I guess that is what the OP wants.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'd like for the entries to be sorted alphabetically still - hidden dirs A-Z, normal dirs A-Z, etc. - and I didn't mean to omit symlinks completely. Probably just need to replace `-type f` with `\! -type d` on those last two lines.

Comment: Perhaps with `find .. -print0 | sort -z`, assuming `sort` supports the `-z` option.

Comment: @muru that finds everything under the parent directory recursively.

Comment: @Koveras I didn't mean the two dots as a path. It was supposed to be three dots (an ellipsis).